# Recoger datos de un formulario y almacenarlos en una tabla (sin base de datos)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp, aspx

necesito crear un formulario parecido a este, cuando rellenos los datos y pulses el botón debería de aparecer justo debajo los datos del formulario en una tabla que se genere de forma dinámica.

-Necesito que los comentarios no se pierdan en los postback.

-Los comentarios se muestren a todos los usuarios en todas las sesiones.

**El resultado debería ser como esta foto** (el css no importa), el formulario lo tengo solo me falta la lógica:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el formulario**

```
<center>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<br />
<br />
<div>
   <!-- Los dos primeros formularios -->
   <asp:TextBox ID="nombre" runat="server" Width="200px" placeholder="Nombre"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="200px" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />

    <!-- Validaciones de los dos primeros formularios -->
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validacionNombre" runat="server"
       ControlToValidate="nombre" ErrorMessage="Nombre de usuario obligatorio" EnableViewState="False" 
       ForeColor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validacionEmail" runat="server"
       ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="El email no es correcto" EnableViewState="False" 
       ValidationExpression="^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$" 
        ForeColor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <!-- Formulario Título -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="titulo" runat="server" Width="430px" placeholder="Título"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <!-- Validaciones de los dos primeros formularios -->
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validacionTitulo" runat="server"
       ControlToValidate="titulo" ErrorMessage="El título es obligatorio" EnableViewState="False" 
       ForeColor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <!-- Formulario Comentario -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="comentario" runat="server" Width="430px" placeholder="Comentario"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <!-- Validaciones de los dos primeros formularios -->
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
       ControlToValidate="comentario" ErrorMessage="El comentario es obligatorio" EnableViewState="False" 
       ForeColor="red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- Botón del formulario -->
    <asp:Button ID="enviar" runat="server" Text="Enviar Datos" OnClick="enviar_Click" />
</div>
<div>
    <hr style="color:black; margin-top: 2rem;" />
</div>
</form>

    <!-- Lista de comentarios -->
    <h4>Comentarios</h4>
    <asp:Table ID="TblPostList" runat="server">

    </asp:Table>

</center>
```

**Este es el archivo .aspx.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    
    namespace WebFormsPracticaUD4Sesion5.Ejercicio_6
    {
        public partial class PostearComentarios : Page
        {
            private List<Post> postPublicados = new List<Post>();
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                   
                }
            }
    
            protected void enviar_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Post post = new Post();
                post.Nombre = TxtNombre.Text;
                if (Email.Txt != null)
                {
                    post.Email = Txt.Email.Text;
                }
                post.Titulo = TxtTitulo.Text;
                post.Comentario = TxtComentario.Text;
    
                postPublicados.Add(post);
    
                TxtNombre.Text = TxtEmail.Text = TxtTitulo.Text = TxtComentario.Text = string.Empty;
    
                crearTabla();
            }
    
            private void crearTabla()
            {
                foreach(var postPublicado in postPublicados)
                {
                    TableRow rownew = new TableRow();
                    Label lblNew = new Label();
                    lblNew.Text = postPublicado.Fecha.ToString() + " " + postPublicado.Nombre + "<br>";
                    lblNew.Text = postPublicado.Titulo.ToString() + "<br>";
                    lblNew.Text = postPublicado.Comentario.ToString() + "<br>";
                    TableCell cellNew = new TableCell();
                    cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
                    rownew.Controls.Add(cellNew);
    
                    
                }
            }
```

**Y esta es la clase Post.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebFormsPracticaUD4Sesion5.Ejercicio_6
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Post
    {

        public Post()
        {
            Fecha = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public DateTime Fecha { get; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Estos son los errores que obtengo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el problema que tienes implementando la lógica?

Comment: El problema lo tengo en el archivo .aspx.cs que me da error en todas las variables TxtNombre, TxtTitulo... Me dice que no existe en el contexto actual.

Comment: Vale, por favor incluye esa información en tu pregunta. Muéstranos qué errores te salen. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/403910/edit) tu pregunta usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: He añadido una foto con los errores que obtengo. En la mayoría me dice "No existe en el contexto actual", pero no sé donde debo declararlos o como solucionarlo.

Comment: Pues en el formulario tienes elementos con ID `nombre` y `email`, en el aspx hablas de `TxtNombre` y `TxtEmail`, pero no sabemos de dónde deberían salir estos últimos. Se supondría que estás haciendo referencia a los elementos del formulario, no?

Comment: Si, pero aunque ponga los nombres del formulario sigo obteniendo el mismo error. Voy a hacerlo como me dices y te cambio la foto, para que veas los errores

Comment: Lo he puesto como me has dicho. Pero en la clase "Post" las variables están con mayúsculas y en el id de los formularios del aspx están con minúsculas. Los ponga como los ponga obtengo el mismo error.